# How to filter objects based on model fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Model named Order that has a foreign key pointed to the current user

```
class Order(models.Model):
customer_name = models.ForeignKey(
settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
on_delete=models.CASCADE,
related_name='customer_name',
)
order_individual_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
order_default_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
order_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
order_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
order_total_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

I currently have 2 order objects from 2 different users. How would I filter the objects so that it only shows the one from a specific user?

I currently have the following code: `Order.objects.filter(customer_name='chironsus')`

It gives me this error: ValueError: `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'chironsus'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'chironsus'` is not the primary key of a `User`, it is perhaps the *username*. You can filter that with:

```
Order.objects.filter(customer_name__username='chironsus')
```

> **Note**: A `ForeignKey` does *not* store the string representation (or name) of the
>   referenced object in the column, it stores the primary key of the record it
>   references in a column with an  `_id` suffix to a `ForeignKey` field. Therefore
>   `ForeignKey`s usually do *not* end with a `_name` suffix. You might want to
>   consider renaming the <s>`customer_name`</s> field to `customer`.